# Using "that" 2 times in a sentence next to itself

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Can I use "that" 2 times in a sentence next to itself?

Comment: I can't see that that is a problem.

Comment: @HotLicks is right, I can't see that that *that* is a problem. That that *that that* in his sentence is clear and unambiguous should demonstrates that *that that* is a perfectly legitimate usage in English.

Comment: That that that refers to in the above sentences is "that".

Comment: @HotLicks Hmm, I'm not sure [That that is is that that is not is not is that it it is](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is).

Comment: I would say that that "that" that that question brings up made me think things through. If this last sentence is grammatically correct, then perhaps five in a row can be correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the words "that that" can appear in a grammatically correct sentence. The first "that" is a relative pronoun (typically used to clarify something), and the second "that" is a demonstrative pronoun (specifying the subject matter at hand).

For example:
"Are you looking for these parts for your vacuum? I found the ones that that machine uses."

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use `that` infinite times in a row and make a proper sentence.

Here is an example:

> That that that that that used was correct.

- The first `that` is specifying *which* `that` you are referring to.
- The second `that`  is the *object* in which you are refereeing to.
- The third `that` is introducing a subordinate clause expressing a statement or hypothesis.
- The finale `that that` follows the first two bullet points.

Think of it as an abstracted version of the following sentence:

> The wrench that the plumber used was correct.

- `The wrench` is the first `that that`.
- `The plumber` is the second `that that`.

This string can actually be repeated infinitely, with punctuation, and still make a proper sentence.

Comment: I think the second instance of 'that' should be italicized or put within quotations to indicate that something meta-linguistic is happening.